# Can Cycles do a Gooch Shader?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

Now that 2.68 [has introduced a toon bdsf](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders#Toon), is it possible to recreate the [Gooch shader](https://www.cs.northwestern.edu/~ago820/SIG98/abstract.html)? Insight, links, or a nodes screenshot would be great.

[image]

Comment: http://www.yaldex.com/open-gl/ch18lev1sec2.html I found this resource with a shader written in GLSL. Converting the fragment shader to OSL wasn't too hard but I'm not sure how to do the vertex shader part. If I make more progress, I'll share it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: Using a model similar to the one in the wikipedia article, I've come up with a complete solution. I also kept my previous attempt included in this post for the comments that refer to it. (Thanks Róbert and gandalf3!)

[image: Gooch final version]

Follow the instructions below.

**Gooch Matte**

[image: Gooch Matte Node Tree]

First, the surface normals from the geometry are combined with a Normal node that manually chooses the direction of the gradient. The dot product of these two vectors is normalized (0 through 1). When dot-product-multiplied against the camera's view vector, the gradient takes on the desired effect. I'm using emission to produce the color and then darkening it down to 10% strength by default (as is described in the paper). The two shaders are added together so that the blue lightens up areas that would otherwise be in complete shadow.

[image: Gooch Matte example plain]
[image: Gooch Matte example with outline]

**Gooch Glossy**

[image: Gooch Glossy Node Tree]

To make a glossy Gooch shader, the Matte is simply added to a Glossy BSDF.

[image: Gooch Glossy example plain]
[image: Gooch Glossy example with outline]

Comment: Why not add some gray in with another [stop in the in color ramp node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Nodes/ColorRamp_Node)? (Ctrl + RMB on the gradient)

Comment: Oh, the gray is there. It's just in the wrong place because Cycles sees the center of the sphere as already "100% shadowed". To write it another way, instead of seeing [bbggyy] the preview sphere is [bbbbgy].

Answer (score 8):

I have a cycles shader that behaves like [matcaps](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Usability). You simply plug in the matcap image to the correct slot. Is it possible that such node setup suits your needs? It renders perfectly smooth around 10 samples. The node setup is complex but I hope it is useful. You could combine it with the freestyle renderer by overlaying the outlines on the cycles render.

Here is a matcap example:

The Cam Down should be usually the real down vector.

[image: Example]

The Matcap Coords node-tree:

The multiply nodes use 0.5 and the add nodes use one.

[image: Matcap Coords]

The Cam Normals node-tree:

[image: Cam Normals]

The Cam Axis node-tree:

[image: Cam Axis]

Comment: Not a bad solution. That would work even outside of Cycles, and since part of the Gooch look is the outlines, Freestyle could take care of them in the same pass.

Comment: Not sure how accurate this would be, but you could set up some color ramps based on normals and maybe [this](http://www.blenderworld.net/2012/09/12/outline-based-on-normals-cycles/) or [these](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/562/how-to-get-silhouette-with-contour-rendering-in-cycles) for the outlines?