# Rendering freestyle lines in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

I've been using BI to render objects as meshes using freestyle edges. I'm now trying to learn to use Cycles. Is it possible to render freestyle edges in Cycles? If so, how?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/562/599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, freestyle is not yet supported in Cycles (and I'm not sure it ever will be directly supported). You could work around the issue by using render layers and grabbing only the freestyle pass from BI:
[image]

Then mixing it with the Cycles pass in the compositor.

Comment: How is this supposed to work?  Blender doesn't allow you to change the rendering engine for render layers.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus, true, but it does allow you to change renderers for different *scenes*. You have to duplicate the scene (after your sure your not going to change it) and set the engine to BI.

Answer (score 6):

## Update

This is [now in master](https://developer.blender.org/rBf75d87bd765fa8d961311eccf979c30665c3d037), and will be in 2.72.

---

This is possible using this [experimental patch](https://developer.blender.org/D632), which may be included in master eventually.

Currently if you want to test it, you'll have to [build blender yourself](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender), or try and find a prebuilt version on a site like [graphicall](http://graphicall.org/?keywords=).