# Is it possible to render outlines in BI/Cycles using this technique for the BGE?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to achieve this [outline effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ss04Dx93Qn0) outside of the game engine for animations, without using freestyle. Is it possible to make this effect work in Cycles or BI?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5248/599

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is quite easy to do in cycles:

[image]

1. Duplicate and scale the object as shown in the video you linked.
2. Add a node setup using the *Backfacing* output of the *Geometry* node to mix a black diffuse shader with a transparent shader. This will go on the scaled duplicate (outline) object to provide the backface culling effect.
3. Disable the *Ray visibility* on the outline object for everything except *Camera* and *Glossy*, *Transmission* if you want to see the outline in reflections and refractions. This will allow light through the outline object, illuminating the main object inside.

### To see the effect in the viewport:

Enable *Backface Culling* in *3D view > Properties panel* (<kbd>N</kbd>) *> Shading*, and set the *viewport color* of the outline material to black:

[image]

## Outlines without extra objects

Also, if you find having an extra object for the outlines rather awkward, you can generate the outline mesh procedurally using a [*Solidify modifier*](http://blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/solidify.html):

2. Add the outline material in another material slot:

   [image]
3. Add a solidify modifier to the object you want to outline, enable *Flip Normals* and set the *Material Index Offset* to the slot where your outline material is (where the first slot is slot `0`, the second is slot `1`, etc.). So in this case, `1`.

   [image]

Now the outline will even update in real time while you are modeling:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Is it possible to see this effect outside of rendering? or would i just hide it and continue with the animation?

Comment: Thats Awesome!, I coulden't get it to show up in the view port quite yet but i just got back from vacation and ill get back to you with my progress. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey will this work in BLender render too?

Comment: @Steven Yes, if you can find a way to enable backface culling. I'm sure there is one, but I can't remember it atm..

Comment: I figures it out, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: rendering this with extra objects in cycles gives just a black outline.