# How to make just 1 object render backface culling and the others not?

Tags: materials

I want to render 2 spheres cut in half one I want backface culling so you only see its normals side and the other I want to see both sides of the faces in the same render.

How do I set render to no backface culling and apply an exception to 1 material?

Comment: When asking about materials please specify what render engine you are using.

Comment: Isn't backface culling used only for shading in 3d viewport in Blender? I can set that in 3d viewport, but "invisible" faces render anyway... only opengl (viewport) render can show that, but for all scene objects, afaik.

Comment: I'll use whatever render will allow me to do this.

Comment: @Eric then, see this question, also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35805/getting-an-outline-with-backface-culling-blender-render

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2083/32466), if you use the Cycles renderer, you should be able to use the backface output from a geometry node to mix between a diffuse and a translucent shader.

This simulates backface culling.

Comment: "use the backface output from a geometry node to mix between a diffuse and a translucent shader." This is too jargony for me to comprhend.

Comment: The linked answer has a relatively deep explanation. In short, select the cycles renderer, go into the node editor, and then modify your material to use the same nodes as in the image in the link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7SG60.png

Answer (score 1):

With  [Cycles](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/introduction.html) render engine you can simply set up a material like this:
The node setup is for the transparent backface.

[image]

In the previous answer the nodes are inverted, if you plug a backfacing in the fac of a mix node, the shader of the backface must be in the bottom slot.