# How do I get an outline for an object without using Freestyle?

Tags: workflow

Guys is there a way I can achieve outline in Blender without using Freestyle, I have a scene of buildings and it's been processing for 15 minutes already, still no results. Blender gets laggy with bigger scenes, so I can't allow myself to duplicate-mesh and do that option for an outline. Got any faster options for outline?

Comment: A solution using a solidify modifier (also works with eevee): https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31194/19156

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50173/freestyle-is-not-exporting-with-the-object/50215#50215

Comment: I can't use solidify as an option, my scene was barely moving as it is, so I just needed something to make the outline in a quicker way, I use this approach for a character or something simpler, this was a long scene so, It doesn't work for me. I did find an option to do the outline in After Effects, using toonit to make an outline out of the render I have made, and then just apply stencil luma blend mode which gives me my original render and the outline using the Effect.