# Obtain 2D Mesh Outline from 3D Mesh

Tags: mesh

I am trying to convert a 3D mesh into a 2D Mesh Outline or Mesh Silhouette. Similar to the MeshOutline Command in the Rhino3D software. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!