# How to get the outline/contour/silhouette of a selected object?

Tags: python, mesh, bezier-curves, vertices, shrinkwrap

I want to use Python to get the outline/contour/silhouette of a selected object in the Orthogonal View.

Just like the orange shape/outline that blender shows when I select the object in the view3D.

As shown below, Blender draws the exact boundaries(or contours, outlines) I want in orange color. How can I get the data of the boundaries (vertices/edge on the boundaries or faces inside of boundaries)?

[image]

As another example, I want to get the contour(orange color), instead of convex hull. (including the vertices `6` and `11` in the result)
[image]
[image]

similar question were asked, but none of the works for me:

[How to extract side-view outline (e.g. top view) of a 3D object to 2D surface?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121119/how-to-extract-side-view-outline-e-g-top-view-of-a-3d-object-to-2d-surface)

[Add outline to object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58839/add-outline-to-object)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN1sz.png)[Turning a complex 3d object into a 2d contour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101525/turning-a-complex-3d-object-into-a-2d-contour)

Comment: Might not be what you're looking for but the contour edges are edges that are linked to exactly one face. Then you can project the mesh onto the view plane to get the outline in the current view

Comment: thank you @Gorgious for replying. I've made it through cv2. I guess there isn't a better way than finding the contours.  If anyone could find a better way doing this, please answer the question or comment!