# Cycles outline objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, freestyle

I want to add the outline effect in all, not only border.

How and can do this in Cycles fast?

I've searched for many pages, but all the methods did not work because I did something wrong.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get silhouette with contour rendering in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/562/how-to-get-silhouette-with-contour-rendering-in-cycles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using freestyle.  Please search freestyle. There are many video tutorials on freestyle. Then show your work.  You may want to use freestyle with Blender Render to reduce time during your learning experience.  You can use the compositor to combine lines with a regular rendered image.

Also you can use the compositor put lines around objects all by itself.  The line can be a glow.  This is possible because Blender can reveal contrast between a transparent background or object id and the surrounding image.

Comment: Freestyle only work good for me, if I set  175 -180 degrees edge detection in options, but blender drawing triangles not squares. In mesh I have squares. I add image.

Answer (score 0):

For rendering the triangulation like that, you could use the Wireframe node (input>>Wireframe).

[image]

For rendering squared faces, it's better to use a square texture with an outline, and use a resetted UVmap.